# Creating a midline for certain classes of pixels in a binary image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have a binary image and I want to draw a red middle line from the white pixels (cars) areas in the image as in the figure. How can I do this in python?

The result I want is as in the image.

this is a question that aims at the parking line by making use of the cars parked in the image.

[image: 1]

Comment: You have to explain better the expected logic, it's currently not understandable without ambiguity

Comment: How is that line defined? The longest line from the lane-center-vanishing-point through the contour?

Comment: yes this is what i want

Comment: Do you already know the vanishing-point?

Comment: yes but i couldn't find how to do it

Comment: For example in brute-force: for each pixel position on left, right and bottom image border: create a line iterator from VP to that pixel; Count the number of white pixels along that line; Choose the one with the highest count in left image half and the highest count in right image half.

Comment: How about trying to do it in Python and if you encounter some problems, you can ask specifically for it?